# In Orchard CMS, Image in Branding breaks when viewing custom content items

Tags: razor, orchardcms

I'm using a custom theme based on "Contoso". I've edited the "Branding" file in my custom theme to show my logo:

```
@{
    var homeUrl = Href("~/");
}
<h1 id="branding">
 <a href="@homeUrl">
  <img src="Themes/myTheme/Content/Images/logo.png" alt="Our Logo" />
 </a>
</h1>
```

I can see the logo fine on regular pages. I've got a list of custom content items on one of my pages though, and when I click on the title of one of the content items in the list to show the details of the item, the logo at the top shows as a broken image... What would cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 <img src='@Href("~/Themes/myTheme/Content/Images/logo.png")' alt='Our Logo'/>
```

Your img url path was not defined as relative to the root. More info here: http://brugbart.com/Articles/paths

This should also work: Notice the '/' at the beginning of the url

```
<img src="/Themes/myTheme/Content/Images/logo.png" alt="Our Logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use

```
<img src="@Html.Content("~/Themes/myTheme/Content/Images/logo.png")" alt="Our Logo" />
```

Comment: Good answer, but it would be nice to explain **why** it's a better option!

Answer (score 0):

Use ~/ as sugested, @Html.Content("~/... 
The compiler tracks the route and makes the URL from the site root, ie, ~/ is replaced by the site's root.